# Программа для расчета силы тока

Tags: c++

Программа, для расчета тока по формуле: I=U/(R+(t/C),где I=сила тока; U=входное напряжение, 10В; t-время, C-емкость, 10 мкФ; Не получается запустить программу, в чем я мог ошибиться?

Код на C++:

```
#include <iostream.h> 
#include <math.h>

{
    float toc(t1,c1,r1,u1)
    return u1/(r1+(t1/c1);
}

void print1()
{
    int i,j,k;
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
        cout <  < "t=" <  < t[i] <  < "i=" <  < i[j] <  < endl;
}

void main()
{
    long float t, c, r, u, i[100], t[100], h, k = 0;
    cin >  > t1 >  > t2 >  > c >  > r >  > u >  > h;
    for(int j = t1; j <= t2; jt = h;
    {
        t[k] = t1; i[k] = toc(c1, r1, u1, t1); k++;
    }        
}
```

Comment: отформатируйте код. кнопка "101010"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Большинство переменных не объявлено.

---

```
{float toc(t1,c1,r1,u1)
return u1/(r1+(t1/c1);}
```

Неправильная расстановка фигурных скобок.

```
long float t,c,r,u,i[100],t[100],h,k=0;
```

Переменная `k`, очевидно, должная быть целой.

```
cin>>t1>>t2>>c>>r>>u>>h;
```

Переменные `t1` и `t2` не объявлены.

```
for(int j=t1;j<=t2;jt=h;             
{t[k]=t1;i[k]=toc(c1,r1,u1,t1);k++;}
```

Нет закрывающей скобки.

Comment: jt-шаг. Он равен 0.1 сек. Счетчик прокручивает время, начиная с 0 сек, до момента, когда значения тока будут сходится на графике, то есть будет близким к нулю.

Comment: а как правильно расставить фигурные скобки?

Comment: @Даниял ознакомьтесь с основами программирования на C++. С помощью книг, [интернета][http://cplusplus.com/], etc.

Comment: @Даниял обновил ответ

Comment: Да, число ошибок превышает количество строк. Компилятор гнется, но не сдается.

Comment: Дело пахнет двойкой

Comment: и не сдался, прога готова.